# handling ajax call with jquery,ebeans in play framework

Tags: jquery, playframework, routes

This is my first time with Play framework and I am trying to design an application that will help manage arrangement of items in shelves of a rack. I have put an background image on a droppable div to display a rack. What I want to do is, on drop function store the images location in the database so that it can be retrieved the next time I enter and position the image in the same location. I am getting the top and left values through

stop: function(event, ui) {

```
    // Show dropped position.
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    $(this).addClass("postn");
    var pos = $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
```

}

displays dropped position

Can anyone tell me 
1)how I should pass the data in the Ajax call
2)how to handle it in Applications method.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: still stuck on this...help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in playframework 2 you can call directly a controller action via ajax example :

```
jsRoutes.controllers.YourController.YourMethod().ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            data: yourData,
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType:'application/json',
            success: function(msg){alert(msg)}
```

in the controller :

```
   @BodyParser.Of( play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class )
    public static Result retrievePlaces(){
response().setContentType( "application/json" );
JsonNode json = request().body().as(JsonNode.class);
JsonNode jsonRequest = request().body().asJson();
String var1= jsonRequest.findPath("yourVar").getTextValue();
String var2= jsonRequest.findPath("YourVae").getTextValue();
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
result.put("status", "OK");
return ok(result);
    }
```

Comment: thanx 4 d help. But I have added an error parameter to the ajax call and it gets executed instead of the success message. I am also working on the insert into db through ebean.

Comment: can you use google chrome and javascript panel for see where the problem is?

Comment: if it is error excecuted it means you have one error in your controller there is nothing in console play? in console javascript? do you put a breakpoint in javascript?

Comment: Thanx Cyril. It works now. Although I am having the following issues: 1)saving the data into the database. and 2) images are not draggable once dropped after the ajax call. Here's the code [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shane05/Q5ZPu/)

Comment: thanx again for your valuable inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get a hold on the ajax call and the Applications method:

```
//AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          url: "@routes.Application.myMethod()",
          data: {
              Left:Stoppos.left,
              Top:Stoppos.top
          },
          dataType:"Json",
          success: function(data) {
                 alert("success");
               },
                error :function(){
                    alert("error");

                }


//Applications

    public static Result myMethod() {
        Map<String, String[]> parameters = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        String top = parameters.get("Top")[0];
        String left = parameters.get("Left")[0];
        System.out.println(top+" "+left);
        return ok(Json.toJson(1));
}
```

I'll post the ebean insert to the db once I get it.

Answer (score 0):

in the success of your javascript you have to call again your JS method maybe try this for all your JS file (it is better when yo use jquery)

```
   !function( $ ) {

     function nameFunction() {
    ...
 }
    nameFunction()
    }( jQuery )
```

i think your javascript is not called, try the javascript debugger in chrome and add a breakpoint in your js code id not pass by the breakpoint your code is not called
so when you are in success call "nameFunction()" please.
If you want use javascript you have to use a javascript debugger!!!!!

Comment: I managed to sort out most of the errors but still get the 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jsRoutes is not defined' error.

Comment: ok sorry in your controller you have to do this :
 public static Result jsRoutes()
  {
  return ok(
  Routes.javascriptRouter( "jsRoutes",
  controllers.routes.javascript.YourController.Your method()
 ) ).as(
 "text/javascript" );
  } ,then in your routes files :GET     /assets/javascript/routes.js   controllers.YourController.jsRoutes and in your html file : <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.YourContoller.jsRoutes"></script>

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new here i don't know how i can do for text formatting in add comment so explanation here : http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaGuide6

Comment: I am fairly new myself and your help so far has been more then appreciated. Although the error of the ajax call is still getting executed. It is throwing a '400 Bad Request' error which means that the server was unable to understand the request sent. Also when you are entering a code select it and press crtl+k to format it.

Comment: no the error is other, sometimes a parameter is missing, now add a breakpoint in your controller you will see the error, otherwise in google chrome if you go to network you will see your error action click on you will see what is you error, there is one error in your console play?

Comment: thank you ;), what navigator do you use? for javascript i recommand goole chrome it is marvelous ;), if you have the error in javascript it would be better... try the breakpoint in controller, look if your parameters required in method are passed....

Comment: I am using Firefox. This is the error firefox showed me 'For request 'POST /myMethod' [Invalid Json]' though the parameters are being past. In chrome it shows the initiator as jquery-1.9.1.js:8526 and the type as text/html.

Comment: ok it i your json in parameter of your ajax call is not good, in the controller the @bodyParser try to parse a non valid JSON, try simply to create a JSON var like : var test = {"test":"test"}

Comment: <div id="start"></div>
<div id="stop"></div>
stop: function(event, ui) {
var Stoppos = $(this).position();
$(this).addClass("postn");
var pos = $("div#stop").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
   
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.myMethod().ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "@routes.Application.myMethod()",
data: {
Left:Stoppos.left,
Top:Stoppos.top
},
dataType: 'json',
contentType:'application/json',
success: function(msg)
{
alert(msg)
},
error :function()
{
alert("error");
}
});

Comment: this is my controller method: @BodyParser.Of( play.mvc.BodyParser.Json.class )
    public static Result myMethod(){
     response().setContentType( "application/json" );
     JsonNode json = request().body().as(JsonNode.class);
     JsonNode jsonRequest = request().body().asJson();
     String var1= jsonRequest.findPath("stop").getTextValue();
     String var2= jsonRequest.findPath("start").getTextValue();
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        //System.out.println("stop"+var1);
        result.put("status", "OK");
        return ok(result);
    }

Comment: your JSON call is not good : instead url : @routes.Application.mymethod put just "url" instead JSON in dataType put "text" like my first example and try to create your own JSON juste for works the call, then adapt your var in data....

Comment: it works, but you pass a non valid JSON , try to solve this probleme and clean your code like my example or play example please ;)

Comment: thanx a ton 4 ur help. Iv made the changes in the ajax call but the '400 Bad request' error persists. The POST is sending the left and top values like "Left=128&Top=196". I'll look into it. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: don't forget you send in JSON so the format is like that {"left":"128","top":"196"} could you vote if my help were useful